# Takes about 1-2 mins to start video in my app using VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, raspberry-pi3

In my application I need to play videos from sd card. I am using android VideoView.

```
private VideoView videoView;
videoView.setVideoPath("path to my video");
videoView.start();
```

It works well on my nexus phone. 
But when I try to use same code on my raspberry pi 3 with os android 6.0.1.
It shows thumbnail and then takes about 1-2 mins before it starts playing video.

I did install bs-player on rPi and it plays video without any delay.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

**update - extra info:**
I tested with different video quality on same video. It took 1min 50s both times to load same video. Even though one file is 24 MB and the other only 9 MB.

Comment: The Pi has very limited memory compared to a phone

Comment: but how does bs-player work then? It also works on low memory on rPi and it has no problem with any delay.

Comment: Probably [hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) or performing some additional downscaling of the video stream

Comment: hardware acceleration is already on.